# AWS Certificate - Unrecognized keystore format: null

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, bouncycastle, iot

I'm trying to generate AWS IoT cerificate from certificate and private key. First I'm creating PKCS12 keystore, then convert PKCS12 keystore to a BKS (BouncyCastle) keystore. While doing second step, I'm getting error:

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format: null
```

What's weird: I'm doing it second time, few months ago I did it the same way, and then it worked, so I'm sure my files are correct. Command I'm using is (new lines only for readability here):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\keytool" 
-importkeystore 
-srckeystore beurer_keystore.p12 
-srcstoretype pkcs12 
-srcstorepass password 
-destkeystore beurer_keystore.bks 
-deststoretype bks 
-deststorepass password 
--provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider 
--providerpath bcprov-jdk15on-160.jar
```

What could changed that this time I'm getting different result? Different Java version? Different keytool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug [1](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1662196), [2](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214100).  I too get the error with macOS / Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode):

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format: null
java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format: null
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:1815)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:1687)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1308)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:397)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:390)
```

I don't get an error using OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.10.1) on Ubuntu 18.10.

I can reproduce the spurious error by simply listing BouncyCastle keystores:

```
keytool -list -v -storepass "donottell" -keystore "ssl/keystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "bcprov-jdk15on-1.61.jar" -storetype BKS
```